# Importing projects into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, import

I have this simple question how to import whole project source into Ecplise so I can browse it easily? Specifically,  I have downloaded Maven source code http://maven.apache.org/download.html and I just want to view it same as other projects in my Eclipse.
I've tried to import it with use of two possible options (as archive and as a project) without luck.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean 'without luck'? Can you explain the problem in more detail? What error messages are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven itself is a Mavenized multi-module project, Generally there are two ways to import a Mavenized project into a IDE like eclipse:

**Pre-requirment**:

- Suppose you have installed Maven 3 and setup environment variable
  properly.
- if you use Eclipse, you also need add M2_REPO to you
  Build Path -- Classpath Variable, check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517507/setting-up-m2-repo-classpath) for how to
  setup. this tells Eclipse where to find jar dependencies stored in
  local maven repository.

**Option 1 -- Import as Java Project**:

- Open a command prompt and go to the extracted source folder, run mvn eclipse:eclipse
  and waiting for it finish, make sure it doesn't popup any message start with [ERROR], this
  will download all required jar dependencies from internet to you
  local maven repository and create .project and .classpath for Eclipse
  to use when doing import.
- In eclipse, go to File -- Import -- General -- Existing Project into
  Workspace, select the extracted source folder as root directory. This
  will import a group of projects into Eclipse as bunch of regular java
  projects (i.e. project icon inside Package Explorer watermarked with a
  capital J).

**Option 2 -- Import as Maven Project**:

- Alternatively, if yo got m2e plugin installed in Eclipse, you can
  directly import the extracted project folder, go to File -- Import --
  Maven -- Existing Maven Projects, select the extracted source folder
  as Root Directory. This will import a group of projects into Eclipse
  as bunch of Maven projects (project icon inside Package Explorer
  watermarked with a Capital M).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The maven repository versions are not uploaded in the exact format they are on disc (from where the the mvn deploy goal is run.  I can think of 3 options assuming I understand your question correctly:

1. You can find the open source project if it exists and get all the
   source and project from there.
2. On an existing project, you go the dependencies, right click on one
       and select browse source. Not the same as having the show project
       here you can build and run however.
3. You can download the sources from the maven repo and then
       reconstruct the project.  I'm not not sure how feasible this
       actually is and I have never tried it. I would probably find other
       ways before trying this.