# How to set maven local repo in java project

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven

I'm new to maven. My team and I are trying to work with maven over git, but when I share my code over git, the .classpath file has a dependency that is pointing to my  user location:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/MY_USERNAME/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-crypto/5.1.0.RELEASE/spring-security-crypto-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar" sourcepath="C:/Users/MY_USERNAME/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-crypto/5.1.0.RELEASE/spring-security-crypto-5.1.0.RELEASE-sources.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="maven.groupId" value="org.springframework.security"/>
        <attribute name="maven.artifactId" value="spring-security-crypto"/>
        <attribute name="maven.version" value="5.1.0.RELEASE"/>
        <attribute name="maven.scope" value="compile"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

This causes config issues for my team members.

- Is there a way the add the `.m2` folder in my project and then reference it in the build path?
- Is that recommended?

I don't want to exclude my .classpath file because I want my team members to receive all the build path configurations, without having to do it themselves.

Comment: https://sookocheff.com/post/java/local-maven-repository/

Comment: http://roufid.com/3-ways-to-add-local-jar-to-maven-project/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven comes bundled with an Eclipse plugin that allows you to easily maintain your .classpath file based on your pom.xml (or project.xml for maven 1.x users) (see [docs](http://eclim.org/vim/java/classpath.html)).

- Initial Setup

  To initialize maven’s support for updating the eclipse classpath you first need to set the `M2_REPO` (or `MAVEN_REPO` for 1.x) classpath variable in the Eclipse workspace by executing the following command in vim:

  *maven 2.x:*

  > `:MvnRepo`

  *maven 1.x:*

  > `:MavenRepo`
- Updating your .classpath

  Once you have performed the initial setup, updating the Eclipse .classpath file is as easy as executing the following at a command line:

  *maven 2.x:*

  > `mvn eclipse:eclipse`

  *maven 1.x:*

  > `maven eclipse`

  or in Vim:

  *maven 2.x:*

  > `:Mvn eclipse:eclipse`

  *maven 1.x:*

  > `:Maven eclipse`

In your case, every team member should follow this procedure every time he/she wants to be up to date with the dependencies each other has updated in the pom.xml.

**Additional readings**:

- [Setting up M2_REPO classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517507/setting-up-m2-repo-classpath)
- [How to add M2_REPO classpath variable to Eclipse IDE](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-configure-m2_repo-variable-in-eclipse-ide/)
- If by any chance you don't have the maven-eclipse plugin, see [Maven in Eclipse: step by step installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620127/maven-in-eclipse-step-by-step-installation)

**Additional Notes**:

Using Gradle you can do it like this:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()      // this uses your local maven repository
        // mavenCentral() // this uses maven central repository
        // maven { url "<some-additional-url-here>" }
    }
    dependencies {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, all I did was run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` in the project and it generated a some directories in the .classpath file like "M2_REPO/org/springframework/security/spring-security-crypto/5.1.0.RELEASE/spring-security-crypto-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar". It cleared all my other configurations but I just had to add back my custom jars to the build path